# SharePoint 2010 Content Editor Webpart not supporting iframe

Tags: sharepoint, iframe, sharepoint-2010, content-editor

I am trying to Embed a SharePoint Site Page in a Content Editor Webpart using iframe in SharePoint 2010. Once i save and close the content editor, the iframe is removed. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Content Editor Web Part is intended for adding HTML content to a Web Part Page, it is not designed to link to a Web site. If you need to link to a Web site, consider using the Page Viewer Web Part. -Microsoft-
[refer this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527).

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you, but I wrote a blogpost about embedding videos like iframes into Rich Text fields.

In short its a script you add to your page through a Content Editor Web Part and after that the users can simply paste the iframe code directly into the rich text field and the content will show.

You could also embed the script into your masterpage.

Anyway, have a look at it and maybe you can modify the script to your needs

[Embed video using script](http://jesper-simonsen.blogspot.dk/2012/11/embed-video-in-sharepoint-2010-blog.html)